# How to convert image file to base64 String in flutter?

Tags: file, flutter, dart, base64

I am try to convert a image file in flutter:

```
 File _img=new File('/data/user/0/com.example.test3/app_flutter/2020-10-29T17:18:56.210347.png');
 List<int> imageBytes = _img.readAsBytesSync();
 String imageB64 = base64Encode(imageBytes);
 print(imageB64);
```

But it look like is a wrong base64 String and I cannot decode to image on convert website:
https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

```
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
```

Is the dart base64 format is different to another?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that this case by the 'print' function cannot display fully base64 code.
If want to verify it, need to export to text file:

```
 _write(String text) async {
    final File file = File('/storage/emulated/0/xxx/my_file.txt');
    await file.writeAsString(text);
    print(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your bytes into an `Uint8List` object not a `List<int>`:

```dart
File _img = File(
   '/data/user/0/com.example.test3/app_flutter/2020-10-29T17:18:56.210347.png');
final bytes = Uint8List.fromList(_img.readAsBytesSync());
final imgBase64 = base64Encode(bytes);
print(imgBase64);
```